# Mootools: Get Textbox Text on Keydown Event

Tags: javascript, mootools, keydown, mootools-events

How can I get the current text of a textbox in the keydown event handler. Calling element.get('value') returns the text that was in the textbox **before the event happened**. How can I get the current value in the event handler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `keyup` event instead :)

```
$('yourTextarea').addEvent('keyup', function() {

    var value = this.get('value');
    console.log('value');

});
```

Comment: Good ;) If for same reason you need to do it in `keydown`, you can retrieve the key that the user pressed (it has to be something like `function(e) { e.key; /* or */ e.code; }`, and use it to append a character to current text.